# Grep: Remove duplicate input from second column

Tags: csv, grep, duplicates

I have a CSV file with two columns:

```
"SKU";"SKU DESCRIPTION"
```

I want to remove the second occurrence of SKU from the second column.

An example.

```
"919";"919 DESCRIPTION"
```

Result should be.

```
"919";"DESCRIPTION"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I'm out of my element here, so far I've tried a variation of
    ()|()

Comment: Do you want absolutely to use `grep` ? You can do it with `sed` too.

Comment: I'm fine with whatever saves me the hassle from looking through 10,020 lines and do it manually column by column. I appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to use `sed` with capturing groups and a backreference to the third capturing group to match the start of the second column with what is captured in the first column.

`^(("([^"]+)";")\3 )`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Td5yMu/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `(` 1st capturing group

  - `(` 2nd capturing group

    - `"([^"]+)";"` Match double quotes and capture what is in between in the 3rd capturing group followed by matching `;"`
  - `)\3` Close 2nd capturing group and match what is captured in the 3rd capturing group by using a backreference followed by a space
- `)` Close first capturing group

Then in the replacement, use the second capturing group:

`sed -r 's/^(("([^"]+)";")\3 )/\2/' file.csv`

If you want to make a backup, use:

`sed -r -i.bak 's/^(("([^"]+)";")\3 )/\2/' file.csv`

Comment: That's excellent! Thanks a lot for your time and solution, much appreciated.